# Why is my code for this BST algorithm question wrong? I am using same logic as the correct solution with one minor tweak and its causing an error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Question is to make the minimum height BST given a sorted array of integers. Logic is pretty much to set node to middle value and recursively do so for left and right subarrays.

The correct solution is :

```
function minHeightBst(array) {
  // Write your code here.
    return bstHelper(array, null, 0, array.length - 1);
}

function bstHelper(array, bst, start, end) {
    if (start > end) return;
    let middleIdx = Math.floor((start + end)/2);
    const newBST = new BST(array[middleIdx]);
    if (bst === null) {
        bst = new BST(array[middleIdx]);
    } else if(array[middleIdx] >= bst.value) {
        bst.right = newBST;
        bst = bst.right;
    } else {
        bst.left = newBST;
        bst = bst.left;
    }
    console.log(bst)
    bstHelper(array, bst, start, middleIdx - 1);
    bstHelper(array, bst, middleIdx + 1, end);
    return bst;
}
```

My solution is as follows and keeps giving the error "Cannot read property value of undefined" :

```
function minHeightBst(array) {
  // Write your code here.
    let bst = null;
    bstHelper(array, bst, 0, array.length - 1);
    return bst;
}

function bstHelper(array, bst, start, end) {
    if (start > end) return;
    let middleIdx = Math.floor((start + end)/2);
    const newBST = new BST(array[middleIdx]);
    if (bst === null) {
        bst = newBST;
    } else if(array[middleIdx] >= bst.value) {
        bst.right = newBST;
        bst = bst.right;
    } else {
        bst.left = newBST;
        bst = bst.left;
    }
    bstHelper(array, bst, start, middleIdx - 1);
    bstHelper(array, bst, middleIdx + 1, end);
}
```

In case you need to see, this is the BST constructor:

```
class BST {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}
```

Example input:

```
 minHeightBst([1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 22]);
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample invocation with data values that results in "Cannot read property value of undefined"?

Comment: @JonTrent Yes, I have added it to the question as an example input.

Comment: Why do you have 2 return statements in minHeightBst?

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Why doesn’t your bstHelper have the return statement?

Comment: @KostasX Sorry, one of them was a typo when I was copying it over. Fixed now.

Comment: @barny Im not sure which line exactly. I mean its obviously happening on the bst.value part but not sure which call to the recursive function. bstHelper does have the return statement in its base case on the first line of the bstHelper

Comment: @Kushh if you follow the guidance of @KostasX [ keep `return bstHelper(...` and get rid of `return bst;` ] and @barny, and throw a `console.log( bst );` in `bstHelper` right before the recursive calls, it appears the results of your routine are the same as the correct solution.

Comment: @JonTrent I'm trying to understand why my incorrect solution is wrong. I understand if I change it to the correct solution that it will work. I'm trying to understand what part of what I did is wrong so I can fix that logic in my thinking

Comment: @Kushh ahhh... A function typically (but not always) returns a value or object, and it seems that you're still grasping that concept.  Here's a good resource to assist... https://codeburst.io/javascript-functions-understanding-the-basics-207dbf42ed99 .

Comment: @JonTrent Like you said, a function does not always need to return a value or object. My goal in my solution is for the helper function to affect the bst as a side effect of its function and then ultimately when the the call stack collapses at the end of all the recursive calls the bst variable will be what I want in my main function and I will return that. I know what a function is lol, i think my confusion may be more around how the recursion is working here.

Comment: @Kushh in such situations, I find that my best friend is the browser debugger, using it to trace the recursion step by step.  In fact, for complex algorithms, I use the browser extensively to assist in development...

Comment: Closely squint at the second `function minHeightBst(array)`: what value do you expect `bst` to have after the call to `bstHelper()`, and why?